# Spring boot application and hibernate are using different naming strategies

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is very strange.

I am using the spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true to create the tables in my database.  When spring does this, the table names are snake case.
For example, the table for `MyClass` becomes `my_class`.

Next, I exported the schema from Hibernate using this code:
[Export schema from Hibernate](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/09/programmatically-generating-database-schema-with-hibernate-5/)

When I call the code, the resulting sql has table names in camel case with the first letter capitalized. So, the table for `MyClass` is `MyClass`.

Why would they generate differently?
How do I get them to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table names are different because Spring configures Hibernate to use a different naming strategy. The naming strategy defines how Hibernate generates the logical name of an attribute or entity and how to map them to the physical name in the database. I explain that in more detail in the [Naming Strategy Guide on my blog](https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5/).

You have multiple options to ensure both of your setups use the same naming strategy:

If you're using a Hibernate version >= 5.5.4, you can configure it to use the `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`. That's the one that Spring is using by default:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit">
        ...
 
        <properties>
            ...
             
            <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy"
                      value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If you're using an older Hibernate version, you might want to change Spring's naming strategy to Hibernate's default strategy. You can do that by setting the following property in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=default
```

If you're using an older Hibernate version and want to use Spring's naming strategy, you have to implement a custom naming strategy. This isn't complex, and I explain how to do it in [my blog post](https://thorben-janssen.com/naming-strategies-in-hibernate-5), but I would choose one of the previously mentioned solutions.

Comment: I am using Hibernate 5.6.5.  I am not using XML so I added `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy` to my `application.properties` file.  It works perfectly.  Thank you!