# Can I run an empty spring boot application without getting an Error?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I just Created this file from spring.initializer.
It is a brand new file. I am trying to run this because I have a previous project that have similar type of error. So I thought of making a new project and see if any error comes. below i the Error

**My Error**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.3)

2022-09-08 20:15:36.021  INFO 8344 --- [           main] c.m.w.webproject.WebProjectApplication   : Starting WebProjectApplication using Java 17.0.4 on DESKTOP-4LDNK11 with PID 8344 (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\JAVA\WebProject\target\classes started by Lenovo in C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\JAVA\WebProject)
2022-09-08 20:15:36.027  INFO 8344 --- [           main] c.m.w.webproject.WebProjectApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-08 20:15:37.266  INFO 8344 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-08 20:15:37.297  INFO 8344 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-09-08 20:15:38.269  INFO 8344 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-09-08 20:15:38.283  INFO 8344 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-08 20:15:38.284  INFO 8344 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-09-08 20:15:38.489  INFO 8344 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-08 20:15:38.490  INFO 8344 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2328 ms
2022-09-08 20:15:38.732  WARN 8344 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
2022-09-08 20:15:38.737  INFO 8344 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-09-08 20:15:38.755  INFO 8344 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-08 20:15:38.789 ERROR 8344 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.mandeep.web.webproject.WebProjectApplication.main(WebProjectApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.lambda$applyNamingStrategies$1(HibernateProperties.java:178) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.lambda$applyNamingStrategy$2(HibernateProperties.java:187) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.applyNamingStrategy(HibernateProperties.java:187) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.applyNamingStrategies(HibernateProperties.java:177) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties$Naming.access$000(HibernateProperties.java:146) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:95) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**My POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mandeep.web.webproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WebProject</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My properties file**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WebProject
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Sciman$@2569
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect


connection.pool.initialPoolSize=1
connection.pool.minPoolSize=1
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000
```

**My Application File**

```
package com.mandeep.web.webproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I See this

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`

**Couple of solutions**

1. Check if you have this class `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy` under your `Maven dependencies -> org.hibernate dependency -> path boot/model/naming`
2. If you can't locate that class, add a hibernate dependency with `version >= 5.5.4`
3. Check if this article helps [Spring boot application and hibernate are using different naming strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391152/spring-boot-application-and-hibernate-are-using-different-naming-strategies)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Hibernate folder from C:\Users{User}.m2\repository.
Then I added below dependency in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also add version to maven plugin -:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  **<version>${project.parent.version}</version>**
</plugin>
```

Do the above steps if anyone gets the same Error.